# Taylor coefficients.

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have a function $$f(x) = e^{-x(2a-x)}$$ It is easy to write out the Taylor expansion for this function in $x=0$ point. But.. I want to get a formula for the Taylor coefficients. I tried a lot. I tried to take derivatives, perform some simple transformations and used the computer, trying to calculate them. Nothing much happened. Maybe there is some clever trick here? I would be very grateful for that.

I got the following expression:
$$f(x) = e^{-x(2a-x)} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kx^k(2a-x)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kx^k}{k!}\sum_{m=0}^{k}\frac{k!(2a)^{k-m}(-1)^mx^m}{m!(k-m)!}=$$ $$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^{m+k}(2a)^{k-m}x^{k+m}}{m!(k-m)!}$$
I thought to designate $m + k = s$ and rewrite the sums in a more convenient form for determining the coefficients, but nothing happened.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think it's better if you share with us what you've done so far. So, do write them out. It will save the time of the people who are willing to help you. Also, add a calculus tag to your question to increase its visibility.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did it.

Comment: Try to write the function as $e^{-a^2}e^{(x-a)^2}$.

Comment: @user, I have tried it, but I do not know how it can help me, since I have an $x^m$ in the sum that is decomposition of $(x−a)^{2k}$.

Comment: For the fun of it, I did the same for $e^{ax+bx^2+c x^3}$ and $e^{ax+bx^2+c x^3+dx^4}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, this is not the most simple problem.

Using brute force, developed at $x=0$
$$e^{-x(2a-x)}=1-2 a x+\left(2 a^2+1\right) x^2-\left(\frac{4 a^3}{3}+2 a\right) x^3+\left(\frac{2
   a^4}{3}+2 a^2+\frac{1}{2}\right) x^4-\left(\frac{4 a^5}{15}+\frac{4
   a^3}{3}+a\right) x^5+\left(\frac{4 a^6}{45}+\frac{2 a^4}{3}+a^2+\frac{1}{6}\right)
   x^6+O\left(x^7\right)$$

Now, searching for a pattern in
$$e^{-x(2a-x)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k\,x^k$$  the $c_k$'s correspond to the recurrence equation
$$c_k=-\frac 2 k(a\,c_{k-1}-c_{k-2})\qquad \text{with}\qquad c_0=1\qquad \text{and}\qquad c_1=-2a$$ I do not think that we could have anything more explicit.

Comment: Upon solving this recurrence relation, I get $c_k = 2^{-k}\left(\gamma_1 ((-2a/n) - \sqrt{4a^2/n^2 + 8/n})^k + \gamma_2 ((-2a/n) + \sqrt{4a^2/n^2 + 8/n})^k\right)$, where $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ are then solved with the initial conditions.

Comment: @TomChen. Sorry for that ! I had a typo in $c_k$. Can you find the solution ?

Comment: I tried brute force, but I did not see a recurrent formula like that of Tom Chen. Now I see and do not quite understand how it turned out.
Moreover, I need to think about how it can help me, but that’s another problem. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @mathmaniac. I think that the problem was my typo. Making the mistake again, I get what Tom CHen gave. I do not think that, as it is, it could be more explicit. To tell the truth, I generated a dozen of coefficients and I found the pattern. By the way, you are very welcome ! Cheers.

Comment: Okay, then I will wait some more time and, if nothing happens, I will mark your post as an answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, I agree with @ClaudeLeibovici now; it appears hunting for a more explicit expression is fruitless. I tried using generating functions to solve this recurrence, only to end up with the original expression $\exp(-x(2a-x))$. Should have expected such a tautology!

Comment: Thanks all of you!